# How to prevent additional characters on input field when max length reached in angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am implementing a directive to stop the user from typing additional characters in the input field in my angular 6 apps. And to allow non-data input keys such as tab, del, backspace etc, and I have an if condition with `event.which`

```
export class MaxLengthDirective {

maxLength: number;

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ngControl: NgControl) {}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event) {
 const element = this.el.nativeElement;
 if (element.value.length >= this.maxLength) {
  if (event.which !== 8 && event.which !== 9 && event.which !== 46)
    event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
}
```

But my `if` condition grows longer when I want to allow more keyboard inputs such `ctrl+ C` or `back arrow` or `shift + tab` etc

Is there a smarter way of handling this nondata inputs on my input control when length exceeds, so that i can still accept non data keys such as tab, del,back arrow etc

Comment: Is not a better approach for you tu use `maxlength="8"` attr of the input? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Have a look at the `pipe`. Even if this is not the perfect situation, is anyway a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

My non-pure angular proposition (allow only alphanumeric keys):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return /[a-z0-9]/i.test(event.key)" [attr.maxlength]="maxLength">
```